# Incorrect wxpython version

Tags: python-2.7, wxpython

I have installed wxPython 2.8.12.1 (unicode) for python 2.7. but when I check the version it shows as 4.0.0b2 msw (phoenix)

[image: wx Version]

When check the version it shows as follows:

> > > print wx.version()                                                                                                  4.0.0b2 msw (phoenix)

Answer (score 2):

There seem to be two possible explanations:

- You have two python instances on your machine and the one where you typed `print wx.version()` is not the one where you installed wxPython classic
- (more likely): You did at one point in time `pip install wxPython` which will currently install `4.0.0b2 msw (phoenix)`

I do not know which version will be imported when you somehow manage to install classic and phoenix.

Recommendation: Uninstall from Windows setup 2.8.12.1 and continue with phoenix.

The only reason to use the completely outdated 2.8.12.1 (released somewhere in 2010/11) is if you have a huge app which cannot be ported to a newer wxPython.